# Should DB types with NULL allowed always strictly map to nullable code types?

Tags: c#, oracle11g, .net-6.0

We are writing modern C# code against a legacy Oracle DB originally designed against C++ code. Historically the convention is we use `NUMBER(10)` for integer values even though in reality the values are never negative.

`ExternalId : NUMBER(10)`

We also don't enforce NULL/non-NULL well in many cases and because this field would be mapped to a C++ integer type in the original code, we have long-standing conventions that `NULL` is treated as 0.

If we are strict to the DDL in new C# code then we would have a class property like:

`public int? ExternalId { get; set;}`

This strikes me as messy/smelly and potentially a misuse of the nullable language feature (which was only introduced in C# 8), but we've run into a disagreement which side has precedence - SQL design or business/system rules?

I'd welcome an answer how to decide which is best in our case. Modifying the database is not a realistic proposition any time soon.

Comment: If your system requires the column to be non-null. Why not change the database so it can enforce this constraint? If your database and code does not agree if fields can be null or not there will likely to be confusion ans mistakes.

Comment: @JonasH changing the database might be ideal but is non-feasible (in the short/medium term) due to non-coding reasons I can't really go into.

Comment: If you cannot change the database I would tend to prefer the intended datamodel, i.e. no nullable fields, rather than being dogmatic about DLL. But I would expect opinions may differ, and opinion based questions are off topic.

Comment: Best is whatever works for you. That said, writing `?? 0` *once* seems innately superior to having it write everywhere that `ExternalId` is used, so if you know `ExternalId` is semantically never `NULL`, you may as well fix it in your data layer and keep the property itself as `int`. The superior place in the data layer to fix this is, obviously, the database, but if that's not an option then the code immediately above it that maps to/from the database will have to bear the burden.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert you put that better than I've been able to :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer to this. It depends on the use case. E.g., if a price of 0$ is a valid price (meaning the article is free) and at the same time it is possible to have undetermined prices (NULL), then you must be able to distinguish between `0` and `NULL`. In other cases, this might not be required.

In a good design the nullability in the DB should match the nullability in the front-end.

If you must deal with a legacy badly designed DB where the columns are nullable just because nobody bothered to think about nullability and 0 and NULL are treated alike, then a non-nullable type in the frond-end is okay.

In an ideal world you would change the DB schema and make those columns NOT NULL, but this is not always feasible because it would break compatibility to other applications.